# Images not load on compile but shown in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, css, fxml

So I'm making an application in java using JavaFX with the FXML files rather than coding the UI in java. To add this project is being handled in Gradle.

I'm using a stylesheet to configure my UI and it's viewing just fine in SceneBuilder however, upon compile and running the code the stylesheet fails the load.

Below is my current file structure (cut out a few things)

```
src
`-- Main
    |-- java
    |   |-- Controller
    |   |   `-- mainWindowController.java
    |   `-- Main.java
    `-- resources
        |-- FXMLs
        |   `-- mainWindow.FXML
        |-- Pictures
        |   `-- image.png
        `-- stylesheet.css
```

below is the section where the FXML file calls the stylesheet.

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="BG" prefHeight="674.0" prefWidth="782.0" stylesheets="@../stylesheet.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.sony.TCOCalculator.Controller.mainWindowController">
   <children...> //Cut out this section
</AnchorPane>
```

Now when compiling I get the error

```
Oct 17, 2018 11:53:21 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not find stylesheet: file:/C:/Users/(username)/AppData/Local/Temp/stylesheet.css
```

I'm pretty confused why this occurs and more so why the compiler is looking for the stylesheet in my temp folder. The same issue occurs when trying to view images, works in Scenebuilder but not long when running.

Below is my main where the FXML file is called.

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private static final String mainWindow = "FXMLs/mainWindow.fxml";
    private static final String mainIcon = "Pictures/mainIcon.ico";
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.debug("Main class has started");
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            File mainScene = openFile(mainWindow,true);
            if (mainScene != null)
            {
                FXMLLoader sceneLoader = new FXMLLoader(mainScene.toURI().toURL());

                Parent root = sceneLoader.load();
                root.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");

                mainWindowController controller = sceneLoader.getController();
                logger.info("{} retrieved successfully", controller);
                logger.info("{} loaded successfully", mainWindow);

                if (root != null)
                {
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.setTitle("TCO Calculator by Sony");
                    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
                    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(mainIcon));
                    primaryStage.setOnHidden(event ->
                    {
                        controller.shutdown();
                        Platform.exit();
                    });
                    primaryStage.show();
                }
                else
                    logger.error("Could not open main scene");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("File does not exist", e);
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
```

you'll notice I manually added the stylesheet in my Main java code but that was just a workaround till I actually solved the problem. The problem has occurred with my Images which I have many of and I'd prefer to add them in my FXML file rather than my java code and so removing the workaround and using the .FXML for loading these things would be a better option.

The OpenFile method is below:

```
 public static File openFile(String path, boolean resource)
    {
        InputStream inFromFile;
        try
        {
            if (resource)
                inFromFile = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);

            else
                inFromFile = new FileInputStream(path);

            if (inFromFile == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            File tempFile = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(inFromFile.hashCode()), ".tmp");
            tempFile.deleteOnExit();

            try(FileOutputStream tempWriter = new FileOutputStream(tempFile))
            {
                //copy stream
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while((bytesRead = inFromFile.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    tempWriter.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            return tempFile;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the resource-files included in your gradle-build? If not than they would not be found?

Comment: @RalfRenz resources folder was created by gradle when making this project in IntelliJ, and main is able to see other resources. It's the StyleManager that can seem to find the resources.